# typescript: trim the rest of the text after a specific number of characters

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, trim, substr

I want to limit text into 15 characters and if it exceeds, the rest of the text should be `...`

How do you do that?

I am using this

```
return txt.substr(15, txt.length);
```

but instead, it removed the first 15 characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(txt.length >= 15) {
  txt = txt.substring(0, 15) + '...';
}
```

OR, if the you still want just 15 characters to be displayed:

```
if(txt.length >= 15) {
  txt = txt.substring(0, 12) + '...';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use also concat function.

```
if(txt.length >= 15) {
 return txt.substr(0,15).concat('...');
} else {
 return txt;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The below `typescript` code worked for me.,

```
let txt = '1234567890FIFTH_REPLACEME';
return txt.slice(0, 15).concat('...');
```

***Working example in JavaScript:***

Click on Run Code Snippet button below and click on "Try It" button to see the results.,

```js
function myFunction() {
    var str = "1234567890FIFTH_REPLACEME"; 
    var res = str.slice(0, 15).concat('...');
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
    return res;
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to display the extracted part of the string.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```